# Sorting ArrayList using Quicksort by a Variable

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new to programming and am currently working on a CompSci degree, I am trying to sort an array list of objects by a variable (Salary) but for some reason it isn't sorting. Could anyone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

```
     public static ArrayList<Employee> sort(ArrayList<Employee> a)
     {
      if(a.size()<=0)
         return a;
      ArrayList<Employee> smaller = new ArrayList<Employee>();
      ArrayList<Employee> greater = new ArrayList<Employee>();
      int pivot = a.get(0).getSalary();
      for(int i=1; i<a.size(); i++)
         {
          Integer n = a.get(i).getSalary();
          if(n.compareTo(pivot)<0)
             smaller.add(a.get(i));
          else
             greater.add(a.get(i));
         }
      smaller=sort(smaller);
      greater=sort(greater);
      smaller.add(a.get(0));
      smaller.addAll(greater);
      return smaller;
     }
```

I was trying to sort an arraylist by a variable (Salary) but the Arraylist isn't being sorted - main code  below using to test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Department marketing = new Department ("Marketing", "test avenue");
        Department admin = new Department ("Admin", "test avenue");
        Department sales = new Department ("Sales", "test avenue");
        addEmployee("A", "1", marketing, 1);
        addEmployee("B", "2", sales, 2);
        addEmployee("C", "3", admin, 342);
        addEmployee("D", "4", marketing, 55555);
        addEmployee("J", "5", sales, 7);
        
        printEmployeeList();
        
        sort(empList);
        
        printEmployeeList();
        
    
    }
```

resulting in:
Employee ID:    1
Name:       A 1
Department: Marketing
Salary:     1

Employee ID:    2
Name:       B 2
Department: Sales
Salary:     2

Employee ID:    3
Name:       C 3
Department: Admin
Salary:     342

Employee ID:    4
Name:       D 4
Department: Marketing
Salary:     55555

Employee ID:    5
Name:       J 5
Department: Sales
Salary:     7

Employee ID:    1
Name:       A 1
Department: Marketing
Salary:     1

Employee ID:    2
Name:       B 2
Department: Sales
Salary:     2

Employee ID:    3
Name:       C 3
Department: Admin
Salary:     342

Employee ID:    4
Name:       D 4
Department: Marketing
Salary:     55555

Employee ID:    5
Name:       J 5
Department: Sales
Salary:     7

Comment: First, you should take the [tour] and read [ask] to see how to participate on this site.  And please include all required classes with getters, setters, toString, equals, etc properly defined.  Your example should be a [mre] so that we can better assist you.

Comment: Your `sort()` method doesn't sort the `ArrayList` that you pass in, it creates a new, sorted `ArrayList`. Within the `sort()` method you correctly handle this (by using the returned lists `smaller` and `greater`), but in `main()` you ignore the returned (sorted) list and instead print out the unsorted list.